# UX work in Scrum during sprints

Tags: ux-designer, research, lean-ux, agile, agile-ux

maybe we can share some experience here.

I am thinking about, how UX Designers can work in Scrum during the sprints. I have so many questions.

As a UX designer, I want to develop user stories with user requirements and wireframes. When do I do this? Our user stories only contain business requirements and the developers should already develop only with them.

When do I do the UX work so that it doesn't turn into a waterfall? Do I hand over artifacts?
Do I develop the user stories completely and then hand them over to developers in refinements?

How do you work as a UX designer in Scrum and in sprints so that it doesn't become a waterfall?

How do you create user stories so that they fit into a sprint?

Assuming I finish the user stories during the sprint, the developers have less time to implement the ticket in the sprint.

Thanks!

Comment: This is far too much to be able to give a correct answer to in a paragraph or two. We need single, specific questions based on actual UX problems that you're having so that we can provide you with the best solution. It seems this post is more of a discussion topic about how to integrate UX with Scrum methodology. That's something you need whole books to cover, not a single Q&A site. So it's not really suited to this site, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scrum.org has several free resources, including videos, blog posts, and more, on integrating user experience with Scrum.](https://www.scrum.org/resources?field_resource_tags_target_id=202&type=All) This represents one perspective from a reputable body. However, it's not the only perspective. I do think there are many ways to integrate user experience with the Scrum framework and what works for one organization may not work for another.

I've primarily seen two main patterns for integrating UX Designers with Scrum Teams.

In one pattern, the UX Designer is aligned with the Product Owner and supports their work in crafting the Product Goal, creating Product Backlog Items, and making sure the Product Backlog Items have sufficient information to be understood by stakeholders. They would typically serve as experts in conducting user research to provide information to the Product Owner, while also maintaining and evolving the design system, planning for A/B testing, and creating any mockups at the right level of granulatity needed to allow the Developers to refine and implement the Product Backlog Items.

In another pattern, the UX Designer is a Developer. They tend to focus on refinement of upcoming work, but may also be involved in the detailed designs and reviewing completed work that impacts the user experience as part of the Definition of Done. In some cases, the UX Designer has sufficient technical knowledge to also be a developer in the software sense and write code related to the user interfaces or that impacts the experience.

Personally, I've seen most success with the first pattern. Especially in a scaled environment where there are multiple teams working on a single product and it may not be economical to either have a UX Designer embedded within each team or ensure that a subset of the teams do work that requires the knowledge and experience of a UX Designer.

By supporting the Product Owner, the UX Designer could be working on earlier concepts and designs and how to evolve the overall design system and information architecture far (perhaps a few Sprints) before the work would be even refined by the development team. The Developers would be able to consume these mockups and proposed changes - which may include concepts from multiple Product Backlog Items - and use them to decompose the work as well as to provide feedback on technical feasibility. The ultimately responsibility to decompose the work would be on the Developers, but the UX Designer would be able to provide guidance on how to evolve the user experience based on how the team can deliver the work.